# Why same query have deferent response time by increase 1 record in rownum

Tags: sql, oracle

Why

```
select * 
  from temp1 tmp1 join 
       temp2 tmp2 on tmp2.fk_tmp1 = tmp1.id
 where Rownum < 48623
```

plan= using index

have response time = *0.23* second

```
select * 
  from temp1 tmp1 join 
       temp2 tmp2 on tmp2.fk_tmp1 = tmp1.id
 where Rownum < (48623 + 1)
```

plan=table full access
response time = *12* second

48623 may be deference in any table

Comment: What's the explain plan on both? Stats up to date? Table size? Indexes?

Comment: And what is the result for `48622 + 1`? `48624`?

Comment: becuase you use a transformation  (48623+1)   ... if you try with 48624 the response time remain the same like 48623... transformation don't use index

Comment: @scaisEdge i doubt that is the reason. I think it is better to inspect the indeces which sadly he did not provide. suppose you have `users` tables with `userid` as `PK`. try run: `select * form users where userid=2` and `select * from users where userid=1+1`   both will use index scan.

Comment: rownum is pseudo internal column and its not have any effect to the used of index . Please share your execution plans of each one of the use cases